# RotMG - not loaded: Version loading error, retrying

Tags: steam, technical-issues, realm-of-the-mad-god

After I installing Realm of the Mad God via Steam, I always get this error:

> Version loading error, retrying...

and after waiting for a long time, restarting, reinstalling and ...; nothing changed!

I also read [Loading version error](https://steamcommunity.com/app/200210/discussions/0/828925849170209740/) post and applying it - installing many versions of flash players/add-ons/etc - , But I get that error continuously!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

> As some sites, protocols or ports that are blocked by many workplaces and school web filters like my workplace, this error will be raise!

I just use an application that *Unblock the internet*, then error goes away!

But if someone knows witch site, protocol or port is related to add them to add it or those to firewall exception, I will accept his/her answer.